# In go reflection package, is the call Value.Kind() a syntactic sugar to Value.Type().Kind()?

Tags: reflection, go

Both of the [reflect.Type](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) interface and [reflect.Value](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) type implement the same `Kind()` method signature, suppose that we have some value object `v := reflect.ValueOf(x)`

Is `v.Kind()` just call `v.Type().Kind()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They contain the same value, but do not seem to refer to the same thing:

- [type.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/reflect/type.go) source
- [value.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/reflect/value.go) source

A `Type` is usually implemented by unexported struct `rtype` (via `TypeOf`), while the `Value` contains a `*rtype` and extends `flag`, which is itself a reduced form of the `Kind`:

```
// flag holds metadata about the value.
// The lowest bits are flag bits:
//  - flagRO: obtained via unexported field, so read-only
//  - flagIndir: val holds a pointer to the data
//  - flagAddr: v.CanAddr is true (implies flagIndir)
//  - flagMethod: v is a method value.
// The next five bits give the Kind of the value.
// This repeats typ.Kind() except for method values.
// The remaining 23+ bits give a method number for method values.
// If flag.kind() != Func, code can assume that flagMethod is unset.
// If typ.size > ptrSize, code can assume that flagIndir is set.
```

When getting the `ValueOf` something:

```
// ValueOf returns a new Value initialized to the concrete value
// stored in the interface i.  ValueOf(nil) returns the zero Value.
func ValueOf(i interface{}) Value {
    [...]
    // For an interface value with the noAddr bit set,
    // the representation is identical to an empty interface.
    eface := *(*emptyInterface)(unsafe.Pointer(&i))
    typ := eface.typ


    /** Flag is built from the type, then kept separate (my comment) */

    fl := flag(typ.Kind()) << flagKindShift
    if typ.size > ptrSize {
        fl |= flagIndir
    }
    return Value{typ, unsafe.Pointer(eface.word), fl}
}
```

And so when you get the kind of a Value (remember it extends its flag):

```
func (v Value) Kind() Kind {
    return v.kind()
}

func (f flag) kind() Kind {
    return Kind((f >> flagKindShift) & flagKindMask)
}
```

While getting the kind of a type: (`Type` is an interface, usually implemented by `*rtype`)

```
func (t *rtype) Kind() Kind { return Kind(t.kind & kindMask) }
```

So although they seem to be equal in most of the cases, `v.Kind()` is *not* `v.Type().Kind()`

Comment: Can Type have the Kind `Invalid`? That may be one case where they differ.

Answer (score 0):

The file [reflect/value.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/reflect/value.go) states that the relevant field in the implementation of `reflect.Value` "repeats typ.Kind() except for method values". So, unless the value is a method, `value.Kind()` and `value.Type().Kind()` return the same number.